# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all and sql injection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my rails app I have some sql function that I run inside on of my classes. Function is called 'survey_loader'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION survey_loader
  a lots of sql here
END;
$$;
```

I also have some facade class to run this functions:

```
# Facade class to expose db stored procedures called from ruby code
class Procedure
  def self.survey_result_loader(administration_ids, survey_result_set_id)
    procedure_name = 'survey_loader'
    params = "some params here"

    select_all(procedure_name, params)
  end

  # Runs SQL function
  def self.select_all(procedure_name, params)
    result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT #{procedure_name}(#{params});")
    success?(result, procedure_name)
  end

  def self.success?(result, key)
    result.first[key] == 't' ? true : false
  end
end
```

But this code is vulnerable to sql injection because params will be passed by user:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT #{procedure_name}(#{params});")
```

How can I rewrite it to be more safe?

Comment: You need to refactor it to use a `where` query instead of `connection.select_all`.  Can you add (to your question, NOT a comment) some examples of the sort of params you would get and the sort of queries you want to make?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend you to use the following class design structure to define your named function. It uses Arel:

```
def self.survey_loader(params)
  @survey_loader = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('survey_loader', params)
end
```

Secondly, as you have hard-coded function name in you `Procedure` class, probably you can rewrite your `self.select_all` method like following:

```
def self.select_all(active_record_model, params)
    active_record_model.select(survey_loader(params))
end
```

Where `active_record_model` is your class, for which you are going to execute the query with your stored procedure.